# JQ - return one array for multiple nested JSON arrays

Tags: arrays, json, nested, jq, data-manipulation

I have a JSON structure that has repeated keys per message. I would like to combine these into one array per message.

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "PolicyItems": [
        {
            "accesses": [
                {
                    "isAllowed": true, 
                    "type": "drop"
                },
                {
                    "isAllowed": true, 
                    "type": "select"
                }
            ], 
            "groups": [], 
            "users": ["admin"]
        }
    ] 
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "PolicyItems": [
        {
            "accesses": [
                {
                    "isAllowed": true, 
                    "type": "drop"
                }
                {
                    "isAllowed": true, 
                    "type": "update"
                }
            ], 
            "groups": [], 
            "users": [
                "admin",
                "admin2"
            ]
        }
    ] 

}]
```

I have this:

```
cat ranger_v2.json | jq -r '[.[] | {"id", "access_type":(.policyItems[].accesses[] | .type)}]'
```

But this outputs:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "access_type": "drop"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "access_type": "select"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "access_type": "drop"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "access_type": "update"
  }
]
```

However, what I want is to output:

```
  [{
    "id": 1,
    "access_type": ["drop|select"]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "access_type": ["drop|update"]
  }]
```

Any ideas how I could do this? I'm a bit stumped!

The values could be 'drop' and 'select', but equally could be anything, so I don't want to hard code these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start by observing that with your input, the filter:

```
.[]
| {id, access_type: [.PolicyItems[].accesses[].type]}
```

produces the two objects:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "access_type": [
    "drop",
    "select"
  ]
}
{
  "id": 2,
  "access_type": [
    "drop",
    "update"
  ]
}
```

Now it's a simple matter to tweak the above filter so as to produce the desired format:

```
[.[]
 | {id, access_type: [.PolicyItems[].accesses[].type]}
 | .access_type |= [join("|")] ]
```

Or equivalently, the one-liner:

```
map({id, access_type: [[.PolicyItems[].accesses[].type] | join("|")]})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found something that I can work with.

If I wrap the query with []...

```
cat ranger_v2.json | jq -r '[.[] | {"id", "access_type":([.policyItems[].accesses[] | .type])}]'
```

... it produces this type of output:

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "access_type": ["drop","select"]
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "access_type": ["drop","update"]
}
]
```

I can then use the following:

```
(if (."access_type" | length > 0 ) then . else ."access_type" = [""]  end )]
```

and

```
(."access_type" | @tsv)
```

Before I can convert to @csv and use sed to replace the tab with a pipe.

```
@csv' | sed -e "s/[\t]\+/|/g"
```

It may not be the most economical way of getting what I need, but it works for me. (Please let me know if there's a better way of doing it.)

```
cat ranger_v2.json | jq -r '[.[] | {"id", "access_type":([.policyItems[].accesses[] | .type])}] | .[] | [(if (."access_type" | length > 0 ) then . else ."access_type" = [""]  end )] | .[] | [.id, (."access_type" | @tsv)] | @csv'  | sed -e "s/[\t]\+/|/g"
```